# How can i limit the input the number of decimals till which user can input value?

Tags: c++

For Eg. Accept 4.55324 as the user input and reject if 6.22356 is entered, i.e accept till 5 decimal places.

Comment: Read as a string, and count the number of characters after the decimal point (which might be different in different locales)?

Comment: Could you give more examples and motivate your question. Why that strange requirement?

Comment: That was the requirement of the question.. just to check concepts

Comment: But after reading http://floating-point-gui.de/ you should understand that the requirement is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to read the input as a string, check that it matches you desired format, and only then convert it to a number.  For example, using the C++11 [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) feature for validation:

```
double number;
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

std::regex pattern ("^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,5})?$");
if (std::regex_match(input, pattern)) {
    number = std::stod(input);
}
else {
    // handle invalid input here
}
```

Note that the regex above is fairly strict: it accepts `12`, `012`, `+12.3`, `-12.34567` and `0.12345`, but rejects `12.`, `.5`, `0.123450` and `1.2e2`.  You may wish to tweak it to match your specific format requirements (whatever they may be).

Comment: I got a thought btw What about this code..

 float a;
 cin >> a;
 a=a*10000;
 float d = int(a)/10000.0;
 cout << d;

Comment: That code will, indeed, truncate a number to at most 5 decimals. (To be precise, it will usually truncate down, but it might round up for numbers like 0.1234599999999999999999, where the precision of a float is not enough to accurately represent the input.) But that's not what you asked for above.

Answer (score 1):

You could read a line as a string using [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) then parse that string according to your needs (and finally convert it to a `double` perhaps using [atof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) on its `c_str()` or preferably [std::stof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)...)

Your examples are not precise enough: should you accept `453.210e-3` or `0.1234567e+3` etc.

You really should read http://floating-point-gui.de/ (I believe your requirements are next to useless)