# adjust the user input in the C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ program for bank to withdrawal money , in that code I used fixed and set precision to change the output for two decimal point but I don't want to do that , I want to make sure the user only need to input in decimal number I mean like only two decimal number .
I want like he/she can't able to enter more than two decimal number .00

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987688/how-can-i-limit-the-input-the-number-of-decimals-till-which-user-can-input-value

Comment: I think the question linked by Omid is a pretty good duplicate. In addition you could take inspiration from [this question about input validation loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075898/good-input-validation-loop-using-cin-c). If you combine both you get the rough idea: 1) Read input as string 2) check if the string is a decimal number with at most two decimal places 3) if the value is valid, convert it to a number, else show an error and prompt again.

Comment: Btw, in financial math **never** use floating point numbers (`float` or `double`). It might work for simple examples, but it's imprecise and will get you in all sorts of trouble when cents start to dissappear or appear out of thin air.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. At least not with standard input and CPP uses the same for taking input.

The best you can do is to take input into a value and cut off the decimal part after the second digit using setprecision(2), or truncate the value once you have it in the variable.

Hope it helped you.